# changing php.ini has no effect on my EC2 instance's PHP config

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running an Apache server in a micro instance from Amazon AWS, and I need to change the session duration and the max upload limit.

When I edit `php.ini` and restart Apache, changes don't show in Apache.

I wasn't able to find any info on this.

What can I do? is there any file overriding `php.ini` that you know of?

Comment: Other config files can be found in `/etc/php.d`

Comment: I have same problem. sudo service httpd restart does not work. However I tried ec2 reboot and it worked. Very strange, apache restart should reflect change in memory_limit but it is not.

Answer (score 33):

Since PHP on Amazon Linux ran with FPM/FastCGI I had to do:

`sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service`

before restarting apache, i.e

`sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`

Comment: Oh, you are brilliant! This is the exact answer to my problem. This should be all over the internet...

Comment: This is what I needed. Drove me nuts

Comment: Worked for me on a 2019 Amazon Linux 2 AMI EC2 - just adding keywords for Google so this answer isn't 15th down the page.  Thanks!

Comment: Pure genius. Thank you. Confirm works for AWS EC2 Linux 2 AMI after updating /etc/php.ini.

Comment: Spent the better half of a day hunting this solution down. Thx!

Comment: What if I'm using nginx?

Comment: I think you have to replace httpd with nginx in ‘sudo systemctl restart httpd.service’. You have to figure that out.

Comment: What's really funny is that I was looking for this answer... and noticed that I already commented on this answer two years ago... and forgotten. See above..

Comment: I received this error: Failed to restart php-fpm.service: Unit php-fpm.service not found.

Answer (score 5):

Which config file are you editing?  When you do a  `phpinfo()` what is the path shown under `Loaded Configuration File`?  Edit the `php.ini` that it says it is loading & your changes should be reflected.

If you don’t know how `phpinfo()` works, just create a file on your server called something like:

```
phpinfo_test.php
```

In that file place this code:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Now load `phpinfo_test.php` from that web server.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, Loaded Configuration File es  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.  I edited that ne and nothing happens. 
I also checked:
Additional .ini files parsed: /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/curl.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/gd.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/zeromq.ini.
But none of those files has anything to do with it. I also did a find inside the server looking for other .ini and .conf files, but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

This is very late, but for those of you who don't know how to handle this problem, you want to restart apache for it to reflect the changes:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 4):

I want to leave the method that worked for me here for others that run into my same problem in language I would appreciate at my level of expertise. I found the location of the php.ini file with the following command in the terminal connected to the server:

```
$ php --ini
```

You will get the following output:

[image]

Change directories to the one specified as "Loaded Configuration File." In the example it is /etc/

Type `cd /etc` into the command line and hit enter.

To override readonly add `sudo` before `vi php.ini` or copy and paste 
`sudo vi php.ini` 
into the command line and hit enter.

Find the place where you would like to make changes and arrow the cursor over it. Press the `i` key to make changes to the document and when you are done hit the `ESC` key.

To save the changes and exit vi, enter
`:x`

I hope that helps. Links to some of the resources that helped me cobble together my solution are below:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=391689

http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/629

http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/how-do-i-quit-from-vi

Answer (score 1):

I just spent some time and discovered, that there were repeat php.ini settings in the end of php.ini file in section AWS Settings. Including upload size and session duration.

Just scroll to the end of php.ini file. Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to edit my php files through terminal accessing the remote file through ssh client which I was editing below through user-detail.
Then the only file I have in my web server is phpinfo.php since i make use of lampp. To add extra file or directory it has to be through  You can best edit web server through accessing the file through terminal. This video assist me greatly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h04jIAIcBhg

Answer (score 0):

You should restart the Apache Server with this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It will work.

Please look at the complete tutorial about [how to change php.ini file in AWS](https://8subjects.com/3-easy-steps-to-change-php-configuration-in-aws-ec2-ubuntu-server-php-ini-ec2/).