# PHP.ini not updating when changing values on AWS EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I've had a problem for a while now where I can't upload anything larger than 8 megabytes. I've narrowed it down that it's the actual php.ini file, which is not updating.

So far I've found 3 different php.ini files, all which I've changed the `post_max_size` to more than the default 8 megabytes. I've tried changing other values too, nothing updates. It's just stuck at 8M

[image]

The three different files are located

`/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`
`/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`
`/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`

When I add a `test.php` to my website and do `phpinfo()`. It tells me that the loaded `php.ini` file is located in the apache2 folder.

[image]

However when I do `php --ini` in my EC2 instance, it shows that the loaded php file is in the cli folder. Like I said I've edited all of them and double checked, all 3 `php.ini` HAVE changes to them.

[image]

Checking the actual php.ini through the command line with `php -info`
I found that it actually had accepted the changes. And I guess this is the CLI php.ini, so that one has updated. But not the apache2 or fpm one.
[image]

I've tried restarting apache2 service. And restarting fpm service according to: [changing php.ini has no effect on my EC2 instance's PHP config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255609/changing-php-ini-has-no-effect-on-my-ec2-instances-php-config)

However in my system it's called `php7.4-fpm` instead of `php-fpm`.
So for me: `sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm.service`

Nothing works.

I can confirm that the services I am restarting ARE the actual services (Or at least the apache2) I'm viewing live on my website. If I close the apache2 service down, my website will stop working. So I'm confident in that at least. I've tried viewing the files I've edited through just editing them via the command line and downloading through ftp. My changes are apparent all the time, but they are just not apparent in practice.

The EC2 instance I'm running is a `t2.xlarge`, running: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) LAMP Stack - Linux Apache MySQL/MariaDB PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem. However a little unconventional, after reading A LOT on the internet finding various solutions and fixes like above mentioned. I finally found something from 7 years ago that **still works today!**

https://serverfault.com/questions/683026/post-max-size-will-not-change-stuck-at-128m-other-settings-work

Here the OP fixed the problem by editing the virtual host config. I did the same and it turns out doing this actually does changes to the php.ini shown with `phpinfo()` on the website. Why this is the case, I have no clue, but it's the ONLY way to change specific variables like:

`post_max_size`
`upload_max_filesize`
`memory_limit`

So like the OP of the link you would find the `sites-available/000-default.conf` wherever it's located in your apache folder usually `etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Add this before the closing tag `</VirtualHost>`:

```
php_value post_max_size 16384M
php_value upload_max_filesize 16384M
```

Then restart `php-fpm` (in my case it's called php7.4-fpm) and `apache2` services in the command line (I'm using the EC2 instance connect)

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

And now you'll see in the `phpinfo()` that it actually changed the local value of the variables we changed in the apache config.

[image]

The master value is still the default, but the site accepts the new local value as the relevant one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the exact path of apache2 in your Instance. It will work.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Check this for [complete guide for php.ini update in AWS ec2](https://8subjects.com/3-easy-steps-to-change-php-configuration-in-aws-ec2-ubuntu-server-php-ini-ec2/)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, I was going creazy.
I could make php read the configuration update restarting the intance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34851738)